# Test automation with BDD Cucumber and Sauce Labs

Tags: cucumber, saucelabs, nightwatch, jira-xray

Hope to find answer here

I have to build a test automation tool with BDD approach written in JavaScript.
We have to use Cucumber, Gherkin, Sauce Labs and it is going to be connected with Xray(Jira).
At first, it was built with help of Nightwatch (to manage webriver) and Nightwatch-api (to manage tests and session in cucumber-conf.js file).

We could connect and run tests with Sauce Labs but we couldn't get any test results in the Test Results Dashboard. It turns out that Nightwatch is not recommended by Sauce Labs anymore and we have to change our approach.

So, I am looking for an alternative now, what we can use to work perfectly with Sauce Labs and Cucumber? To handle Gherkin feature files, create Cucumber reports, to communicate with xray?

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: Take a look at webdriver.io

Comment: Thanks a lot! WebdriverIO handles the job!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to continue using Nightwatch for your tests, consider looking at other cloud-hosted testing services that allow it. Check [this one](https://loadero.com/features) out, you can create cloud-hosted tests with Nightwatch there.